# Probability Intersection Theorem

Tags: probability

The question was wrong as currently put and didn't make any sense.
The actual question should be: finding the intersection of the Cartesian product:[image]

Comment: A correct statement is $A \le B \Rightarrow A(B \cap C) = AC \cap B$.

Comment: @Rain, look for *Dedekind's Lemma* on Stackexchange or the Internet and you will find what you are looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not true without further restrictions:

Let $A = B = G$ be nontrivial and $C = \{1 \}$. Then $AB \cap C = \{1 \}$ whereas $(A \cap B)C = G$.

Comment: It's still not true. Take $A=B=1$ and $C=G$. Then $AB \cap C = 1$ and $(A \cap B)C=G$.